# Use C# to remove nested entries in JSON

Tags: c#, arrays, json

I have the following JSON that I need to use.

```
    {
    "globals": {
        "shirt": "red",
        "shift": "night",
        "activeUsers": 0
    },
    "users": {
        "37328": {
            "customso": null,
            "xp": 11872,
            "hours": 1268.86035,
            "amount": "0",
            "hoursannounce": 0,
            "rank": "Assistant Gamemaster",
            "active": 0,
            "activecount": 0,
            "level": 16,
            "creditRedeemed": 1,
            "creditTime": 22.000021,
            "activeCount": 0
        },
        "48573": {
            "customso": null,
            "xp": 1238,
            "hours": 12.33921,
            "amount": "0",
            "hoursannounce": 0,
            "rank": "Player",
            "active": 0,
            "activecount": 0,
            "level": 2,
            "creditRedeemed": 1,
            "creditTime": 22.000021,
            "activeCount": 0
        },
        "38272": {
            "customso": null,
            "xp": 4039,
            "hours": 5.47362,
            "amount": "0",
            "hoursannounce": 0,
            "rank": "Player",
            "active": 0,
            "activecount": 0,
            "level": 4,
            "creditRedeemed": 1,
            "creditTime": 3.003343,
            "activeCount": 0
        }

    }
}
```

What I would like to do is use C# to remove the activecount variable from the JSON. I get that I could do something like..

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
JObject header = (JObject)jo.SelectToken("users.37328");
header.Property("activecount").Remove();
json = jo.ToString();
```

But the issue becomes that I don't know how to do it to EVERY entry (37328, 48573, 38272, etc). I'm thinking perhaps I can get a list of those entries, then use the list to cycle through them using a for/next loop to apply the above code to each one. But I don't know if this is reasonable when it comes to cycles or if there is a better piece of code that will just do all the entries..

EDIT: @zaitsman got it right. Thank you. That code works perfectly.

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var userProp in jo["users"].Children()) {
    ((JObject)userProp.Last).Property("activecount")?.Remove();
}
json = jo.ToString();
```

Comment: Map the JSON string to an object with an IEnumerable of those and loop through them?

Comment: Maybe a bit of a rough solution but you parse the Json into  a list of objects. And then cast each one of those object into another object without the property you want to remove, and then back into json. Very rough and Im 100% sure there is a better solution.

Comment: Select the `users` node and use `Children` to get an enumerable list of entries. Then iterate over them. Or, to riff on @JosipJuros' solution, just deserialize into a type without that property. Depends on what you're going to do with the JSON later...

Comment: @HereticMonkey That wont cause an error saying "Expected format does not fit?" ??

Comment: Not in my experience. But maybe my serialization settings are weird...

Comment: Yeah it shouldnt give that error, my mistake.

Comment: @HereticMonkey

"Select the users node and use Children to get an enumerable list of entries. Then iterate over them."

Can you show me code that would do that as an example please? I'm not new to programming, but very new to C# (the code sample I gave is the answer for a different question on here that seemed useful).

Comment: @HereticMonkey

"Depends on what you're going to do with the JSON later..."

This is read in by a bot I use to process various things. It uses magic I believe and would need to stay the same format as listed (though the variable I want to remove is one that I had put in manually).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the JSON you posted `users` is an `object` not an `array`.
You can remove these properties like so:

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var userProp in jo["users"].Children()) {
    ((JObject)userProp.Last).Property("activecount")?.Remove();
}
json = jo.ToString();
```

Comment: I didn't downvote you, but when I run it, I get back the error of.. [2022-06-06 07:00:38.105 ERR] InlineCode :: There was an error running the instance for ''
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Comment: The whole code is 

  string globalsFilePath = @"data\globals.dat";
  var json = File.ReadAllText(globalsFilePath);

  JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
  foreach(var userProp in jo["users"].Children()) {
   ((JObject)userProp.Last).Property("activecount").Remove();
  }
  json = jo.ToString();

  File.WriteAllText(@"data\globalstest.dat", json);

Comment: @LanceLake apparently NOT all your users contained that property, a `null-propagation` operator fixes that (see my edit)

Answer (score 0):

@zaitsman got it right. Thank you. That code works perfectly.

```
JObject jo = JObject.Parse(json);
foreach(var userProp in jo["users"].Children()) {
    ((JObject)userProp.Last).Property("activecount")?.Remove();
}
json = jo.ToString();
```